# Ubuntu 18.04 Dock mouse hover tooltips - how to disable?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock, tooltip

I need to know if it is possible and how to disable the Ubuntu 18.04 Dock tool-tips for mouse hover the pinned application.

[image: Ubuntu Dock]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no direct or simply way to configure what we need in question.
But it can be done by editing the User Shell theme that is in use.

if you are using default theme in 18.04, below is the way to achieve.

first take back up of `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file.

now open the file with you favorite text editor, mine is gedit, so

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

go to line number 1205 and find the below content.

```
.dash-label {
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  color: #eeeeec;
  background-color: rgba(46, 52, 54, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  -x-offset: 8px; }
```

Change it to

```
.dash-label {
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  color: #eeeeec;
  background-color: none;
  font-size: 0pt;
  text-align: center;
  -x-offset: 8px; }
```

save the file & close. Reboot to see the change.

[image]

if you use different User-Shell themes, you may find same content and editing it as above.

Comment: Got it done ... i made a copy if the file content as backup version and i apply the changes as stated .. after rebooting Tooltips were gone ..

Comment: @PRATAP, very nice touch. Probably you best recommend to edit the original file, which is /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css. All other files link to that one. Yet, the header of the file says " do not edit because the file is generated. There might be a better and more persistent way to effectuate the change (aka editing another file). Yet, for now, the hack may do the job.

Comment: is it possible to set a timeout instead of completely hiding the tooltips?

Comment: oh sorry the timeout is hardcoded..

Comment: Hello, is there a way to disable the tooltips in Ubuntu 20.04? because the css file doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi.. now a days dash to panel or dash to dock have the capability to hide it with a turn on and off switch.

Comment: @PRATAP could you please elaborate on how to do that on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: did you install those extensions one by one? then you can easily find the option..

Comment: @PRATAP: Which extension??! if you reply to my comments, please consider mentioning my name so I get a notification about it.

Comment: `dash-to-dock` and `dash-to-panel` @Navaro

Comment: @PRATAP: No, I don't use those extensions

Comment: those extensions have a switch to turn off tooltips.. @Novaro Are you looking for Ubuntu Dock only??

Comment: @PRATAP: Sorry, I don't get notifications about your replies. Yes, I want only to disable tooltips for Dock only as shown in the image above.

Comment: @Navaro can you raise a new question with your requirement so that you will get what you are looking for..

Comment: @PRATAP: It is exactly the same question but for Ubuntu 20.04. I mean your solution worked for me when I was using Ubuntu 18.04, but now, in Ubuntu 20.04 it doesn't work.

Comment: @Navaro ok.. so editing css file is ok for you??

Comment: @PRATAP: I tried to edit the css files in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` and restarted but that didn't work.

Comment: @Navaro I request you to raise a new question for Ubuntu 20. 04 and mention the link of this question that you tried it and you are trying to achieve this with Ubuntu Dock only.. mean while I will also work out for the new question..

Comment: @PRATAP: done: https://askubuntu.com/q/1255340/545149

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo vim /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

or

```
sudo nano /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

or any text editor launched with **sudo**..

Search: `.dash-label`

You will see something like:

```
.dash-label {
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  color: #eeeeec;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  -x-offset: 8px;
 }
```

**Backup it**. Then replace or comment with /* ... */ old and add:

```
.dash-label {
  font-size: 0;
 }
```

Comment: S_Flash .. i followed the instruction from PRATAP .. but I have a question??? the file you are suggesting is pretty much the same but it is in different path and is the ubuntu.css .. what is the main difference ..

Comment: Somme tweak tools, extensions can use backup css + some themes can use different names and path's.

Comment: Thanks .. I appreciate .. both of you were very helpful ..