# Ubuntu 20.04 How to disable mouse hover tooltips over Dock

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock, tooltip

When I was running Ubuntu 18.04, I used the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1095366/545149) to disable the tooltips when hovering over the dock by the mouse. After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, that solution no longer works.

Is there a workaround to disable tooltips for Dock only as shown in the image below?

[image]

EDIT: I am using the Yaru theme if that matters:

[image]

Here is the content of `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme`:

```
├── calendar-today.svg
├── classic-process-working.svg
├── classic-toggle-off-intl.svg
├── classic-toggle-off-us.svg
├── classic-toggle-on-intl.svg
├── classic-toggle-on-us.svg
├── gnome-classic.css
├── gnome-classic-high-contrast.css
└── Yaru
    └── gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using Yaru-dark as shell theme..

so edit the file `/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
```

around line number 1493 add the line as below..

```
.dash-label {
  background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.925);
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
  color: #eeeeec;
  font-size: 0pt; # Added This new Line
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  -x-offset: 8px; }
```

My final edits are

```
.dash-label {
  background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0);
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 0pt;
  padding: none;
  text-align: center;
  -x-offset: 8px; }
```

[image]

Comment: For the edits to take effect without rebooting, Press `Alt` + `F2` then type `r` and press `Enter`.